# Axios - get request URI data from the response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios

So, I'm trying to migrate a node project from using **request.js** to use **axios.js**

When I'm using the request package I'm able to get the URI data from the response object like this

```
request(req, (err, response) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.request.uri);
  console.log(response.request.uri.hash);
  console.log(response.request.uri.host);
});
```

But when I use axios like this

```
axios(req)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.request.uri);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I'm getting *undefined* for the **response.request.uri**

So, Am I using the axios package wrong and there is another way to get that information I want or axios just doesn't support that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Matt Weber's answer after you get the `url` from `res.config.url` you can directly parse it using `url.parse` and access the `.hash` `.query` from there.

For example:

```
const url = require('url')
console.dir(url.parse('protocol://host.com/?q=q1#hash'));

// Outputs:
Url {
  protocol: 'protocol:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'host.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'host.com',
  hash: '#hash',
  search: '?q=q1',
  query: 'q=q1',
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/?q=q1',
  href: 'protocol://host.com/?q=q1#hash'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can access it by accessing `response.config.url` **or** `response.request.responseURL`, though if you only want the URI you would need to use regex or you could use JS by utilizing a array or string method.

**Example:**

```
const axios require('axios');
const url = require('url');

axios(req)
  .then(response => {
    const parsedURL = url.parse(response.config.url);
    console.log(parsedURL.host);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**If you don't need the parsed URL info and don't want another package:**

```
// Remove the URL Protocol (https:// & http://) using regex. 
const removeHttpProtocol = (url) => url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '');

axios(req)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(const responseURI = removeHttpProtocol(response.config.url);
    console.log(responseURI);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Yeah but what if it errors?